# Restoring a hyper-V backup to a different Hyper-V server

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v

Windows 2008 R2 server with Hyper-V being backed up with Windows Server Back up using VSS.  Could I restore the vhd and xml files, then transfer them to another server and run them (assuming the server was very similar, both with Xeon CPUs, but slightly different models?

Comment: I don't see why that wouldn't work. It should essentially be the same as exporting and importing the VM.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it's not going to be that easy. The XML file is going to be configuration specific, and Microsoft only really supports using the "export" function of Hyper-V Management or restoring the whole server using the restore functionality associated with the full server backup.

You may have some luck trying to restore an individual item using the `wbadmin` tool but I doubt that'll work as the machine you're restoring on is different. So I suggest that instead of using your existing backup process to restore that machine for this one edge case, you should instead export the VM from the first server and then import it into the second.